# jQueryUI modal dialog doesn't block RETURN keyup event (or ESCAPE)

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-events

I'm using a jQueryUI modal [dialog](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-modal) widget to simulate an "alert" box.  It all works as expected, with keyboard input being blocked while the dialog is open, except that if I close the dialog with the <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd> key then I get a stray "keyup" event hitting my application.  Why is this happening, when a modal dialog is supposed to block all input?

Here's a JSfiddle demonstrating the problem - https://jsfiddle.net/kmbro/x7w6hLtg/ - and here's some code to make StackOverflow happy about the JSfiddle link :-)

```
$("<div/>").dialog({ modal: true, ... });
```

While `dialog()` appears to be the culprit for allowing the <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd> "keyup" event to leak, I don't think it's responsible for <kbd>RETURN</kbd>.  This seems to centre on how button "click" events are generated by the <kbd>RETURN</kbd> key, because they fire on "keydown" whereas using the spacebar to press the button triggers the "click" on "keyup", so the dialog has closed before the "keyup" event occurs.  You can see this by pressing the <kbd>Click Me!</kbd> button by tabbing onto it and pressing <kbd>RETURN</kbd> - the dialog opens on "keydown".  If you press the button using <kbd>SPACE</kbd> instead then the dialog doesn't open until the "keyup" when you release the key.

The question is, what's so special about <kbd>RETURN</kbd> that is triggers a "click" event on "keydown" and not "keyup"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the RETURN key triggering "keydown" - "click" - "keyup" is simply the way browsers work - see https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/15194 - so I'll just have to learn to live with it.